# Where is the boundary between an adjective and a noun adjunct?

Tags: morphology, parts-of-speech, lexemes

My working model is thus: An **adjective** should be flexible in that it can describe a variety of nouns. A **noun adjunct** looks like an adjective but can only be connected to a limited number of nouns. So, *hot* oven and *microwave* oven show 'oven' described by an adjective and a noun adjunct, respectively. But may I apply the same method to words that appear to be adjective-like but function like a noun adjunct, and vice versa? Examples follow.

1. ***Gordian.*** To me, *Gordian* is a noun adjunct, in spite of its suffix, because it basically can only be used to describe 'knot' ([see Ngram Viewer data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%3D%3EGordian_ADJ&year_start=1988&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bknot%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKnot%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bknots%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIII%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNew%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BKnots%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BII%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B_ROOT_%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BYork%3D%3EGordian_ADJ%3B%2Cc0), refresh the search to see the results, if needed)
2. ***Fermi.*** On the other hand, *Fermi*, when not used in reference to the person, can be an adjective because it can modify a variety of nouns ([Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%3D%3EFermi_ADJ&year_start=1988&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blevel%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Benergy%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsurface%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDirac%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blevels%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliquid%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgas%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfunction%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsurfaces%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmomentum%3D%3EFermi_ADJ%3B%2Cc0)).

Is my reasoning sound? Do you have other criteria to distinguish these parts of speech?

Comment: Since there is no real difference between adjective and N' adjunct, you can make the terminological distinction any way you want.  Who cares?

Comment: There's also whether the word can be used predicatively (The oven is hot, *The oven is microwave), but then you also run into problems like 'The sequence is Cauchy, and therefore convergent', which seem to suggest that 'Cauchy' is an adjective. (This agrees with your prediction though, since a distribution, a series, the mean value theorem, etc, can also be Cauchy).

Comment: The parts of speech labels are not affected by the function of the word in the clause. They are simply modifiers and may be nominal ("a **brick** wall") or adjective ("a **long** letter"). Btw, I'd use the term 'adjunct' for modifiers and supplements in clause structure, not phrase structure.

Comment: I care because I'm making a discrete list of eponyms which requires boundaries, and I've chosen adjectives. Cauchy, incidentally, is on my list, though I wasn't sure whether people would accept using it predicatively. Thanks! Yet it feels strange for me, a non-mathematician. Furthermore, can radiation be Hawking? Can a test be Turing? Hmm... It seems much easier for a curve to be Gaussian, or a network to be Bayesian, than a level to be Fermi, despite "Fermi level" occurring more frequently than "Bayesian network". I found no examples of Fermi used predicatively. The suffix matters, it seems.

Comment: @BillJ, sorry, I don't quite understand why PoS labels wouldn't be affected by the function. One reason this concerns me is I'm trying to understand how PoS taggers analyze corpora. If you wouldn't use 'noun adjunct' the way that I have, could you offer an alternative? For example, 'attributive noun'?

Comment: Bill was saying that PoS labels aren't affected by the functions of words *in specific clauses* (they are, however, defined according to their functions in clauses in general, as well as other morphosyntactic criteria). This principle, while usually observed by (general, non-computational) linguists, doesn't seem to be well accepted in CL/NLP, perhaps for practical reasons.